# Add new column with number of visit using dplyr

Tags: dplyr

I have clinical data with patient followup visits after a procedure.

The data are grouped by patient and procedure (each patient can have more than one procedure).

I then have the date of every follow up visit.

```
library(tidyverse)

#Current Data
tribble(
  ~PT_CODE, ~PROCEDURE, ~DATE,
  "A", "A41", "Jun-01-2010",
  "A", "A41", "Aug-01-2011", 
  "A", "C29", "Jul-01-2012", 
  "A", "C29", "Jul-04-2013", 
  "B", "F64", "Sept-01-1989", 
  "B", "Q72", "Oct-01-1990", 
  "C", "S21", "Nov-01-1991", 
  "C", "S21", "Dec-01-1992", 
  "C", "S21", "Dec-01-1993", 
)
```

I would like to add a column, "visit_number" that counts what number followup visit is for that procedure.

```
#Desired Data
tribble(
  ~PT_CODE, ~PROCEDURE, ~DATE, ~visit_number,
  "A", "A41", "Jun-01-2010", 1,
  "A", "A41", "Aug-01-2011", 2,
  "A", "C29", "Jul-01-2012", 1,
  "A", "C29", "Jul-04-2013", 2,
  "B", "F64", "Sept-01-1989", 1,
  "B", "Q72", "Oct-01-1990", 1,
  "C", "S21", "Nov-01-1991", 1,
  "C", "S21", "Dec-01-1992", 2,
  "C", "S21", "Dec-01-1993", 3
)
```

I assume the code will start like this:

```
data %>%
group_by(PT_CODE, PROCEDURE) %>%
arrange(DATE) %>%
_______?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number()` fits what you're looking for!

```r
library(tidyverse)
#Current Data
df <- tribble(
  ~PT_CODE, ~PROCEDURE, ~DATE,
  "A", "A41", "Jun-01-2010",
  "A", "A41", "Aug-01-2011", 
  "A", "C29", "Jul-01-2012", 
  "A", "C29", "Jul-04-2013", 
  "B", "F64", "Sep-01-1989", 
  "B", "Q72", "Oct-01-1990", 
  "C", "S21", "Nov-01-1991", 
  "C", "S21", "Dec-01-1992", 
  "C", "S21", "Dec-01-1993", 
)

df |> 
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, format = "%b-%d-%Y")) |> 
  group_by(PT_CODE, PROCEDURE) |> 
  arrange(PT_CODE, PROCEDURE, DATE) |> 
  mutate(vist_num = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#> # Groups:   PT_CODE, PROCEDURE [5]
#>   PT_CODE PROCEDURE DATE       vist_num
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <date>        <int>
#> 1 A       A41       2010-06-01        1
#> 2 A       A41       2011-08-01        2
#> 3 A       C29       2012-07-01        1
#> 4 A       C29       2013-07-04        2
#> 5 B       F64       1989-09-01        1
#> 6 B       Q72       1990-10-01        1
#> 7 C       S21       1991-11-01        1
#> 8 C       S21       1992-12-01        2
#> 9 C       S21       1993-12-01        3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>